# Can we get netsuite inventory update at any endpoint like webhook?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to get real time update at my system whenever any inventory update in Netsuite. I read about [SuiteScript 2.x User Event Script](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4387799721.html) Type but still have doubts what if inventory is updating via some warehouse using other integrations.

Please direct me to possible solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A User Event script will still work for that, even if the update is coming from an integration - you just need to ensure the script deployment includes all the relevant execution context types.  For example, if the integration accesses NetSuite via SOAP Web Services, make sure that SOAP Web Services is selected in the Execution Context field under the Context Filtering tab of the Script Deployment record.  Also make sure you deploy the script to all transaction types which can affect inventory.

Best practice for this type of setup would be to also have a Scheduled or Map/Reduce script as a backup, which can perform the required updates on any records where the user event failed for any reason.  An example where this would come into play would be if the system you are updating is offline for any period of time.

Another thing to consider is: do you *really need* **real time** updates?  Because a User Event which accesses a remote system will need to wait for the required network calls and processing, which could have an appreciable impact on user experience while waiting for those transactions to save.  Other options are:

1. Make the updates entirely schedule based (Scheduled or Map/Reduce script types).  These can be run as often as every 15 minutes, so your system should only ever be as much as 15 minutes out of date.
2. If 15 minutes is still too much, you can have your User Event call a Scheduled or Map/Reduce script using the N/task module.  This would give an asynchronous execution, or *near* real time without the UI impact of a long running user event.

Comment: Thanks Krypton for your response and suggestion. Yes, I need real time inventory sync. I'll try your suggestion with Scheduled and post my updates once done.