# How to get update for Netsuite sales order status change or fulfilment update to my server?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to get update at my system whenever any sales order staus change/fulfilment update in Netsuite. I read about [SuiteScript 2.x User Event Script Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4387799721.html) but still have doubts what if status/fulfilment is updating via some import csv, integrations.

Please direct me to possible solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we get netsuite inventory update at any endpoint like webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77021304/can-we-get-netsuite-inventory-update-at-any-endpoint-like-webhook)

Answer (score 0):

A user event script is a script running server-side.
This script is triggered with the integration too.
For the CSV update, there is a check box to mark to allow to trigger user event script.
I recommend using an after-submit script that will take the information and push it to your own database.

Comment: Can you please be more specific where the checkbox is?

Comment: When you use the import assistant, in the import option, you will have a check box that allow you to trigger the scripts

Comment: Thanks. I had to expand the Advanced Options section.

Comment: Thank AnthoVdo, I'll check and post my update once done.